# Graph API search pages and applications using php-sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am looking for -

- Sample on how to use graph api search pages to get me started.
- Does the api include applications in the search?
- Do i need an access token to use this feature, i did not see in the docs?

Comment: the search does not include applications, and you do not need an access token for page search.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to get a search for applications?

Comment: No not that i can see in the docs.  We support search for the following types of objects:

All public posts: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post
People: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user
Pages: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=platform&type=page
Events: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event
Groups: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=programming&type=group
Places: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,122.427&distance=1000
Checkins: https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=checkin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this sample assumes you have php-sdk 3.1.1 installed. and are using a form to submit the search to current page.  url format sample.com/?qs=search+facebook

---

```
    $q = urlencode($_GET['qs']);
    if(!$_GET['qs']){
    $q = urlencode($_POST['qs']);
        if(!$_POST['qs']){
        $q = "facebook";
        }
    }
$MEsearch = $facebook->api('/search?q='.$q.'&type=page&limit=100');
foreach ($MEsearch as $key=>$value) {
    foreach ($value as $fkey=>$fvalue) {
    $pagename = $fvalue[name];
    $pageid = $fvalue[id];
    $pagecategory = $fvalue[category];
echo ''.$pagename.' '.$pagecategory.'';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, i will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I've been doing with Ajax. Make a php file (fbAuth.php, in this example), first :

```
require_once("fb_sdk/src/facebook.php"); //Path to FB SDK

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'yourappid',
  'secret' => 'yourappsecret',
));
$query = urlencode('searchterm');
$type = 'post';
$ret = $facebook->api('/search?q='.$query.'&type='.$type);
echo json_encode($ret);
```

And then, using jQuery :

```
function fb_fetchPosts(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "fbAuth.php",
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    success: fb_success
  });
}

function fb_success(posts){
  posts = $.parseJSON(posts);
  //Do stuff here
}
```